# AWS DynamoDB select query with date range

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is it possible in **AWS DynamoDB** to query using **date ranges**? For example if I have table named **students** in MySQL we can do

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE created_at > "2015-11-25 10:10:00" AND created_at < "2015-11-29 00:25:00"
```

I am relatively new to AWS DynamoDB. I understand it is completely different from RDBMS. But this particular requirement (querying using date ranges) will help me to migrate a huge amount of data to DynamoDB and save some cost.
Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Notes:-

1) students is not the real table name.

2) I will be having more fields in this table other than **created_at**

3) My application will be REST APIs, which will be done either in RUBY or **JAVA**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Java. But if you use ruby and this gem: https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid, you could query for `greater/less than` relations pretty much like Mongoid:

https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid#range-finding

Comment: Expecting some solution in JAVA too